# Spring & AOP : getting pointcut configuration right

Tags: spring, session, transactions, aop

Looking at the below two classes and AOP configuration, I'm uncertain about whether this is right at all? I've configured a pointcut on the PartnerService, but only use the session in PartnerDao. Will this safely begin a new session (and transaction) which I can use in PartnerDao?

These are my classes

**PartnerService.java:**

```
public class PartnerService {

    private PartnerDao dao;

    public void setDao(PartnerDao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }    

    PartnerDao getDao() {
        return dao;
    }

    public List<Partner> getPartners() {
        return getDao().getPartners();
    }

    public void createPartner(Partner partner) {
        getDao().createPartner(partner);
    }

}
```

**PartnerDao.java**

```
    public class PartnerDao {

    private HibernateTemplate template;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.template = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
    }    

    HibernateTemplate getTemplate() {
        return template;
    }

    public List<Partner> getPartners() {
        return getTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback<List<Partner>>() {

            @Override
            public List<Partner> doInHibernate(Session s) throws HibernateException {
                Criteria c = s.createCriteria(Partner.class);
                return c.list();
            }                    
        });        
    }

    public void createPartner(Partner partner) {
        getTemplate().save(partner);
    }
```

}

Now, I'd like to use AOP to manage transactions.  I've got the following AOP configuration in applicationContext.xml:

```
<aop:config>        
    <aop:pointcut id="serviceMethods" expression="within(com.company.pas.service.*)"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="companyTransactionAdvise" pointcut-ref="serviceMethods"/>
</aop:config>
```

If you look at my AOP configuration, I'm configuring a pointcut for the PartnerService (which is located in com.company.pas.service). However, I'm only dealing with the session in PartnerDao. The way I'm instantiating these classes is that I've got a ServiceFactory which returns a PartnerService with an autowired instance of PartnerDao.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using [Spring AOP Transactional Management](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)? Using annotations it will be as easy as annotating your Service methods with `@Transactional`.

Comment: Isn't that what I'm using already? I've got an AOP config which a configured <td:advice /> use to control transactions. I'm using XML configuration though as I like to keep configuration and classes separated.

Comment: Oh ok sure, it wasn't clear that you do the AOP config through the 'tx' namespace as a tx:advice to pass through the transaction-manager. So what's the problem then? As long as you call the DAO methods from within the Service ones that are the entry points for your transactions you are good since still in the same transaction initiated. It's common practice to add transactional support in the Service layer that is internally making use of the injected DAOs.

Comment: What I don't quite get is that if AOP starts the transaction when I enter the service class, how does the transaction manager know that it is the session (HibernateTemplate) available through the related DAO it should commit when I leave the service class? Furthermore, if my service class use two different DAO's each with their own session (HibernateTemplate), how does AOP know that these two sessions are related and should be atomic? This would be very easy to achieve using "coded" transaction demarcation in my service class...but I don't get how AOP can figure out all this by itself?